# How to access subprocess exit code

Tags: error, shell, unix

I want to write function that passes current line and file to external program and saves its output into register, e.g:

```
function Foo()
  let l:current_line = line(".")
  let l:current_file = expand("%:p:S")
  let @" = system("command-foo " . l:current_file . " " . l:current_line
endfunction
```

Problem with that code is that if external command fail, function will succeed, but will store error message into register instead of regular output. How can I get exit code of `system` invocation, so I can do error checking?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Thanks for looking for a duplicate of your own question too...